# How to Load Localhost Image in mobile device when react native app in development?

Tags: android, image, react-native, localhost

I am implementing on simple app in `React Native` in which, I need to load image from server.

For that I am using `axios` for make `http` call and get result from local server.

Now, I am getting result perfectly. Problem is that  **Image URL** is of **localhost**

So that, that **URL** is not load in my mobile device because images are not exist in `mobile device`.

Is there any configuration that can enable to load **localhost** image into mobile device ?

Comment: http://192.168.0.1:PORT/url

where 192.168.0.1 is System IP

Connect mobile device & Local host system on same WIFI

Comment: Thanks For your suggession, But I have already tried this solution, By convert `localhost` into `machin's Ip`, But My backend can't return all Url with IP address.
Is there any other Solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand why you need to use Axios to download an image and present it. The `<Image>` component takes in a `source` prop which can have URI key for your Image URL